# How to choose the xstream converter

Tags: java, converters, xstream

I have a entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity {

  public Map map1;

  public Map map2;
}
```

Using XStreams, I want to use the default map converter for map1 and my own map converter for map2. How can I do this?

Comment: Add an annotation in the field @XStreamConverter(MyOwnConverter.class)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before and I got an exception: `ObjectAccessException: Cannot construct MyMapConverter, none of the dependencies match any constructor's parameters`

Comment: My converter was not `public`. After setting it public, it works with `@XStreamConverter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an annotation in the field `@XStreamConverter(MyOwnConverter.class)` as shown [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html).